# Starting a Java process with the same executable as the current

Tags: java

I have some Java code that launches a new Java process, effectively using the default system JRE (in my case JDK 8). Instead I need it to run with the version that is running the original process (e.g. JDK 9).

How can I do that? (The solution needs to work on both Java 8 and 9.)

## Details

The code currently relies on the default system JRE by simply issuing a `java ...` command. An alternative would be to use something akin to `System.getProperty("java.home") + "/bin/java"` (but platform independent), but both have the same problem (for me): They launch a Java process with the JVM version known to the system.

**UPDATE**: *That's utterly wrong, `System.getProperty("java.home")` indeed does what I want and returns the current JVM's home directory. (Stupid me, I thought I tried that.)*

One way to launch with the same Java version, would be to ask the current process for it's executable and reuse that one, but I found no API for that.

Comment: `System.getProperty("java.home")` gives you the current JRE, not a default JRE

Comment: @IngoKegel You're totally right, I have no idea how that escaped me... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot use the new Java 9 API yet, here you go:

```
static String getJavaRuntime() throws IOException {
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
    String java = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator +
            (os != null && os.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).startsWith("windows") ? "java.exe" : "java");
    if (!new File(java).isFile()) {
        throw new IOException("Unable to find suitable java runtime at "+java);
    }
    return java;
}
```

For more details you can take a look how we do it in JOSM's [restart action](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/browser/josm/trunk/src/org/openstreetmap/josm/actions/RestartAction.java), which has the following requirements:

- work on Java 8+, Linux, Windows and macOS
- work with java running a jar file or class files directly (e.g. from an IDE)
- work with Java Web Start and macOS packaged applications
- work with paths containing space characters

The code proceeds as follows:

- finds the java runtime using `java.home` system property
- checks whether the `sun.java.command` system property is available (not the case for IBM JVM), then extracts program main class and program arguments from it.
- reconstructs the command line either by adding `-cp` or `-jar` arguments, depending on what we found at previous step
- runs the command using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`

There is also a lot of stuff concerning JNLP (WebStart) and macOS applications. I assume you're not interested in it but I can explain it if you want.

Comment: But doesn't that use the executable found in the `java.home` system property? Because that doesn't fit my bill.

Comment: It should be fine. All of our tests show that `java.home` property is filled in with the current Java runtime, not the default system one. Did you check?

Comment: I'm sure I've tried that but I'm starting to discover the same... weird. I'll be back after more tests...

Comment: Shorter version: `Path java = Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.home") , "bin", (...) ? "java.exe" : "java"); if (!Files.isRegularFile(java)) ...`

Answer (score 4):

Solution for Java 9 only. With

```
ProcessHandle.current().info().command().map(Paths::get).orElseThrow();
```

you get a handle to the current java executable: `<JAVA_HOME>/bin/java[.exe]`

Now, use that (absolute) path with the new Process API to your liking.

Comment: That isn't by any chance a Java 9 API, is it?  I need this to work on Java 8 as well (will clarify the question).